# norm fit producing incorrect fit

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Why does the following produce an incorrect output for muf and stdf?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
x=np.linspace(-50,50,100)
sig=10
mu=0
y=1/np.sqrt(2*sig*sig*np.pi)*np.exp(-(x-mu)*(x-mu)/(2*sig*sig))
muf, stdf = norm.fit(y)
print muf,stdf
```

This prints
`0.00989999568634 0.0134634293279`

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's incorrect? What would you expect instead?

Comment: I would check the definition of `norm` and compare this to your equation of `y`. Do they give the same values for the sam einput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of `scipy.stats.norm`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm) says for its `fit` function

> `fit(data, loc=0, scale=1)`    Parameter estimates for generic data.

To me this is highly ununderstandable and I'm pretty sure that one cannot expect this function to return a fit in the usual sense.

However, to fit a gaussian is rather straight forward:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(-50,50,100)
sig=10
mu=0
y=1/np.sqrt(2*sig*sig*np.pi)*np.exp(-(x-mu)*(x-mu)/(2*sig*sig))  #

def gaussian_fit(xdata,ydata):
    mu = np.sum(xdata*ydata)/np.sum(ydata)
    sigma = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.sum((xdata-mu)**2*ydata)/np.sum(ydata)))
    return mu, sigma

print gaussian_fit(x,y)
```

This prints 
`(-7.474196315587989e-16, 9.9999422983567516)` which is sufficiently close to the expected values of `(0, 10)`.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood the purpose of `norm.fit`. It does not fit a Gaussian to a curve but fits a normal distribution to data:

```
np.random.seed(42)

y = np.random.randn(10000) * sig + mu
muf, stdf = norm.fit(y)
print(muf, stdf)
# -0.0213598336843 10.0341220613
```

You can use `curve_fit` to match the Normal distribution's parameters to a given curve, as it has been attempted originally in the question:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x=np.linspace(-50,50,100)
sig=10
mu=0
y=1/np.sqrt(2*sig*sig*np.pi)*np.exp(-(x-mu)*(x-mu)/(2*sig*sig))

(muf, stdf), covf = curve_fit(norm.pdf, x, y, p0=[0, 1])
print(muf, stdf)
# 2.4842347485e-08 10.0000000004
```

Comment: Very nice concise answer. Thank you.